# Brainstorming Recreation of MODO Contour Tool

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh, knife-tool

currently working out how to reproduce [MODO's contour tool](https://youtu.be/oUbVAmYll4A?t=8) in Blender.

I've tried a couple methods and ran into road blocks. Below is a snippet into my attempts. Ideally this script would be a low level Bmesh operation. Right now I'm focusing on 'User Placed Mesh to Slice Master Mesh'.

**I'd like feedback on how to best approach this contour slice script.**

**Attempt No. 1 route:**
Best way to limit 'bmesh.ops.bisect_plane' to Plane intersection faces?

**Attempt No. 2 route:**
Ideas on how to make 'knife_project' ops a low level bmesh function?

[image]

Thanks for reading

Comment: You CAN limit the geometry that gets bisected, you just have to select the wanted geometry beforehand in edit mode

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, so my question is: How to limit geo through bmesh. I would need to find intersecting faces between Plane and Master Mesh. Not sure how to find + sel. those specific verts/faces.

Comment: @bkost is that not  an optimisation (of Select All > Cut >  Deselect All But Cut), and therefore maybe important, but secondary?

Comment: @bkost CgCookie's Retopoflow have same functionality. Take a look at their code on how they approach it. This may be starting point. I'm not sure : https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow/tree/master/retopoflow/rftool_contours